# font-face not working in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I can't have the fonts of font-face when using IE11.

I have the following CSS:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "DINCONDMED";
   src: url('https://mysite/fonts/din-bold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
   src: url('https://mysite/fonts/din-cond-med.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
   url('https://mysite/fonts/din-cond-med.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
   url('https://mysite/fonts/din-cond-med.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
   url('https://mysite/fonts/din-cond-med.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
   /*url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');  Legacy iOS */
}
```

The developer tools of IE11 show this:

[image]

I don't know how to solve this problem. Thank you for the help